# Cross-schema Foreign Keys

Tags: mysql

Can a foreign key in one MySQL database/schema refer to a table in a different database/schema?

If so, what limitations are there on doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you just need to specify the schema before the table name. For example, if the referencing table is in schema `qa` and the referenced table in `xx`:

```
ALTER TABLE qa.test_results 
    ADD COLUMN file INTEGER,
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (file) REFERENCES xx.files (file) ;
```

Then all of your queries will also need to be formatted using `schema.table`

Comment: Correct except for the code. The syntax would not add a foreign key. Edited and fixed.